# IIS rewrite rule to redirect when {REQUEST_URI} is not empty

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to redirect when REQUEST_URI is not empty. For example, for a incoming request like:

```
https://www.mydomain
```

I need to stay to:

```
https://www.mydomain
```

However for a request like:

```
https://www.mydomain/products/customized
```

I need to redirect to:

```
https://www.otherdomain/products/customized
```

How should I write this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule to achieve you requirement.

```
            <rule name="Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".+" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://otherdomain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]

Has the request url

[image]

Comment: If you feel my answer helps you, please mark it as answer. This will help other people who faces the same issue.